# Universal Hub App sample does not return right number of items when trimmed

Tags: c#, json, windows, xaml, windows-runtime

I’m trying to edit the Windows Store Universal Hub App sample in VS 2013. There is a SampleDataSource.cs that takes in data from a SampleData.json, and presents it when asked for. The method I’m interested in is SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync. Assuming I have 10 items in a group (in the json file), I’d like to display only 6 on the landing page (HubPage), and all 10 on the SectionPage (the page you get when you click on the Hub Section header).

So I modified the code to do this.
HubPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
    var sampleDataGroup = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync("Group-4");
    // Trim items to top 6 only
    if (sampleDataGroup.Items.Count > 6)
    {
        for (int removeIndex = sampleDataGroup.Items.Count - 1; sampleDataGroup.Items.Count > 6; removeIndex--)
        {
            sampleDataGroup.Items.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
        }
    }
    this.DefaultViewModel["Section3Items"] = sampleDataGroup;
}
```

However, when I navigate to SectionPage, I only see 6 items, instead of all 10. Why does this happen? I am calling SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync again, the original collection or the json file was not modified by my trimming down to 6 items, so why am I receiving only 6 from SampleDataSource? I have confirmed that this is indeed “Group-4”
SectionPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
    var group = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync((string)e.NavigationParameter);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
    this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = group.Items;
}
```

Here is a direct link to the samples. I'm using the C# version:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Universal-Windows-app-cb3248c3

Comment: Could you provide a link to download page for the sample code?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I've added a link to the question

Comment: I actually need Update2  applied to be able to view that sample - Time to update!